# Python : New Url instead of New Webbrowser

Tags: python-2.7

i want my script to go to a new url instead of opening the webbrowser countless times

here is my script :

```
import random
import webbrowser

results = []
with open("al.txt") as inputfile:
   for line in inputfile:
         results.extend(line.strip().split(','))
x = (random.choice(results))

While True: 
    webbrowser.open(x)
```

Comment: The "countless times" will be caused by the `while True:`...
And if you want to open the URL in a new tab you can use [`webbrowser.open_new_tab`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/webbrowser.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the docs, included in the code below, it's not possible to open one page then go to a new site with the same tab. You can however open a new tab in the same browser, with the following:

```
import webbrowser
webbrowser.open('https://docs.python.org/2/library/webbrowser.html',
new=2, autoraise=True)
```

This will open as many tabs as necessary. Hope that helps.

**EDIT : Needs to close page now.**

Use the following function, it makes use of subprocess module, opens a Chrome browser, closing it afterwards.

```
from   subprocess import Popen
import subprocess

def call_browse(url):
    fp  = 'C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\\'
    tsk = Popen([fp+"Chrome.exe",url ],shell=True)
    time.sleep(10)
    Popen('taskkill /F /IM Chrome.exe')


url ='https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html'
call_browse(url)
```

Comment: what about closing the old tabs after opening a new one?

Comment: @Furkancan Türksoy You can't close a browser with that module, a brief glance at the documentation would have made that clear: you'll need to use subprocess instead, see the updated code.